# Upper bound on altitude of triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In a triangle of base $a$ the ratio of the other two sides is
$r(<1)$. Show that the altitude of the triangle is less than or equal to $\frac{ar}{1-r^2}$.

I noticed that for a triangle of base $a$, for any given altitude $A$, it is always possible to construct a triangle in which the other two sides are in ratio $r(<1)$ by considering an isosceles triangle with base $a$ and altitude $A$ where the two equal sides are other than the base, and by shifting its apex perpendicular to the altitude to the extent that it is required to obtain a ratio of $r(<1)$ between the other two sides. If my observation is right - and if it is not, I would appreciate it if somebody could explain why - how can be there be an upper bound on the altitude?

Comment: HINT.-Note $a,cr,c$ the sides and since $h_a=\dfrac{2A}{a}$ where $A$ is the area you have, using Heron formula, to bound
$$h_a\le \dfrac{2}{4a}\sqrt{(c+cr)^2-a^2)(a^2-( c-cr)^2)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let sides of length $a, b, c=br$ correspond to angle $A, B ,C$ and let the height be $h$.

Using the area of triangle and sine law $b\sin(A)=a\sin(B)$,

$${1\over 2}ah = {1\over 2}b^2r\sin(A) = {1\over 2}a^2r{\sin^2(B)\over \sin(A)}$$

Simplify, $$h = ar{\sin^2(B)\over \sin(A)}$$

Note that

$$\sin(A)=\sin(B+C)\geq\sin(B+C)\sin(B-C)=\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)$$

the last equality is a known fact where proof can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-proof-of-sin-2A-sin-2B-sin-A+B-%C3%97sin-A-B)

Also since $r={\sin(C)\over \sin(B)}$, therefore

$$h = ar{\sin^2(B)\over \sin(A)} \leq ar{\sin^2(B)\over \sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)}=ar{1\over 1-({\sin^2(C)\over \sin^2(B)})^2}=ar{1 \over 1-r^2}$$

Comment: I understand this proof, but I don't know how to reconcile it with my observation. Obviously, something in my observation is wrong, but I can't put a finger on it. Can you help?

Comment: No, you cannot shift in such way to obtain any arbitrarily small given $r$. If the height is extremely tall there is a lower bound on how small your shifted $r$ can get, namely the one given by the inequality stated in the question (and as shown in the proof where B and C are differed by 90 degree). After that point both the sides will increase in length and the ratio becomes larger.

Comment: So, I was thinking when the altitude is $ar/(1-r^2)$, if the shorter of the two sides is vertical, then the ratio should be r, and once it ceases to be vertical with the continued shifting of the apex to the left or to the right the ratio should become greater than r, right? I am interested in analyzing the limiting case, but the issue with this reasoning for the limiting case is that the Pythagoras theorem is not satisfied for the sides $a$, $ar/(1-r^2)$, and $a/(1-r^2)$ where the third side is the hypotenuse.

Comment: How did you know to use that equality?

Comment: The first step is to come up with the form $h=ar\times$something, and then try to make that something equal to $1\over{1-r^2}$. Working backward will lead to proving $\sin(A) \geq \sin^2(B) - \sin^2(C)$ and the logic follows. It's not like knowing to use it from the beginning.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.